# I want to print a text and a variable with a number together

Tags: python

I am trying to create a tax calculator, but each time I try to add two numeric variables, I get an error. I have tried googling many different types of solutions, but do not understand many of the solutions posted on Stackoverflow or Reddit. So I decided to post my own question, despite someone already asking the similar question.

Example code:

```py
    Price= float(input("What is the sale price of your item?:"))
    GST= Price * 0.05
    PST= Price * 0.07
    Total = Price + GST + PST
    resulttext = "The total cost of this item is"
    print(resulttext + Total)
```

Getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\donal\PycharmProjects\untitled\BC Total Sale Price Calculator.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(resulttext + Total)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
```

Comment: `print(resulttext + str(Total))` or better yet `print('{} {}'.format(resulttext, Total))`. If `python >= 3.6`, then `print(f'{resulttext} {Total}')`

Comment: Hi Donald, please have a look at `python f-strings` https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/ if you are using python3. Will be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
print(resulttext + str(Total))
```

`Total` is of type `float`, you need to convert it to a `string` to concatenate and output it. Or even better, just use the fact that arguments separated by a comma into the `print()` function in python are implicitly converted to a string.

```py
print(resulttext, str(Total))
```